# How to pick a random element from a vector filled with .txt file names C++

Tags: c++, text, random, vector, generated

I stored a long list of names from a .txt file into a vector called BunnyNames, and I am trying to find a way to randomly generate elements (names) from within said vector.  So far all it's doing is printing the names consecutively from the .txt file instead of randomly like I want.  Here is my code:

```
int main()

{
    using namespace std;

    string name;
    vector<string> BunnyNames;

    ifstream myfile("names.txt");

    if(!myfile)
    {
        cerr <<"Error opening output file"<< endl;
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    }
    while (getline(myfile, name))
    {
        BunnyNames.push_back(name);
    }

    srand (time(0));
    int randomIndex = rand() % BunnyNames.size();

    std::cout<<BunnyNames[randomIndex]<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I only want it to print one name at a time, but I want that one name to be random.

Here are the first few lines of the file:

```
Abracadabra
Ace
Akeeta
```

Comment: You print it only once for now. Is it your actual code or not?

Comment: how are the file names separated in the .txt file? If it's printing all the names, then all the names are in your first (and only) element of your vector. Check the size of your vector.

Comment: Secondly, have you tried printing BunnyNames one by one? Does it produce expected results?

Comment: Please copy paste first few lines of names.txt

Comment: The C++ standard library have many nice [algorithms built in](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), for example you could use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) together with a predicate that [randomly](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) returns `true`.

Comment: If all filenames are in the same line try replacing the getline with `    while (myfile>> name)`

Comment: I updated my original post at the bottom to answer your guys' questions.

Comment: @AdamSchmidt, So post the code about which the question is. Now it doesn't do what you say it does. Otherwise it does look fine to me - it should work without problems.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: that's just wrong on many levels. It's resource consuming. The code is more complex to understand. A naive implementation with a fixed probability will give you non-uniform distribution and there's a chance it won't return anything. I see many cons, no pros..

Comment: If you see so many cons, why don't you suggest a way to optimize the code?

Comment: your code is already "optimized". it's easy to understand *and* fast.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that you want to randomly access vector elements, this might be because you are setting the seed inside the loop.

Try seeding it only one at the beginning and use `rand() % BunnyNames.size()` inside the loop as:

```
srand (time(0));
while(condition)
{
    int randomIndex = rand() % BunnyNames.size();
}
```

Another case might be that the loop is iterating fast enough that in successive iterations, the time doesn't change, thus generating same values.

Comment: What loop are you referring to?  The OP's code only generates one number.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I interpreted it as OP is trying to access multiple elements in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help everyone.  It turns out that it was in fact printing out random names, but I didn't catch it because the names still appeared to be going alphabetically.  I didn't realize that it was skipping groups of names at a time, depending on how long it was before I re-ran the program (since srand (time(0)) is based off of time).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, if you run the program repeatedly in close succession, you use the same, or very similar seeds (because the time doesn't change much).  You need to devise a way to either generate a wildly different seed each run of the program, or create a random number generator which you can save the state of.  For example, you could do this:

```
unsigned int seed = time(0);
std::ifstream fin("rand.txt");
if (fin)
{
    fin >> seed;
    fin.close();
}

srand(seed);
seed = rand();
unsigned int randomIndex = seed % BunnyNames.size();

std::ofstream fout("rand.txt");
fout << seed;
```

It saves the generated number from the previous run of the program into a file, then uses that value for the seed on the next run.